# Convert a p-adic number to a vector in Pari/GP

Tags: pari, pari-gp

I want to extract the elements of a Pari/GP p-adic number to a vector. I.e., if this is my p-adic number:

```
O(5^8)+1/3
> 2 + 3*5 + 5^2 + 3*5^3 + 5^4 + 3*5^5 + 5^6 + 3*5^7 + O(5^8)
```

I want to be able to extract a vector like this:

```
[2,3,1,3,1,3,1,3]
```

Is there a direct way to do this or do I have to write my own function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PARI/GP has no built-in function to select the i-th component of p-adic expansion. You can define it on your own:

```
padic_comp(x, i) =  truncate(lift(Mod(x, x.p^(i+1))) / x.p^i)
```

Note, `x` is of t_PADIC type, and `i > 0` is integer s.t. `x.p^i < x.mod`.

So, for your example the vector can be obtained easily:

```
x = 1/3 + O(5^8)
vector(8, i, padic_comp(x, i-1))
> [2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3]
```

Comment: `inconsistent  t_PADIC , t_INTMOD.`, this solution doesn't work? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please, provide MNWE. The example in my answer works well for PARI/GP v2.11.2.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can just `lift` it to an integer and use the `digits` function to get the digits - which then need to be reversed:

```
 Vecrev(digits(lift(O(5^8)+1/3), 5))
```